# What is the @ symbol in Latex used for? I had seen its use in the tables as given below

Tags: tables, symbols

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Attribute\\  No\end{tabular}}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: It serves for inserting things between columns of the table. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#@-expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of the `array` package:

> @{decl.} Suppresses inter-column space and inserts decl. instead.

So here `@{}` sets the space on both sides of the unique column to 0.